# Getting intellisense on static string

Tags: typescript, intellisense

I have the following helper:

```
function createAction<Payload>(type: string): (payload: Payload) => ({
  type: string;
  payload: Payload;
}) {
  return (payload: Payload) => ({ type, payload });
};
```

And then i use it like so:

```
interface Payload {
  howAreYou: boolean;
}
const RequestName = 'GoodThanksHowAreYou';
const action = createAction<Payload>(RequestName);
```

I want the intellisense when hovering over "action" to show that the type is `GoodThanksHowAreYou` but it just says string.

I know i can achieve this with generic types, and do something like `createAction<Type extends string, Payload>` but it makes the "use" of this helper more complicated.

Comment: One solution would be to use currying

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need a type parameters that will capture the type of the input argument `type`.

```
function createAction<Payload, Type extends string>(type: Type): (payload: Payload) => ({
  type: Type;
  payload: Payload;
}) {
  return (payload: Payload) => ({ type, payload });
};
interface Payload {
  howAreYou: boolean;
}
const RequestName = 'GoodThanksHowAreYou';
const action = createAction<Payload, typeof RequestName>(RequestName);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQWvMAHgAUMBPAGzgwBMAaRAFTIAc1E0APbMGgZ0R8oKGGADmAPgAUUVmgBcTOQEpFUluSq1FpStRrLEAXgmIpAbwBQiRLLaLmbANzXEGvdsS6tNFwF9DKxt0KBAUJHVNfR0o2kMTM3NbOQZ3H0QA-xdRbBRgDAh2b31EIMQACzgAdxx0AE04EEUAIzg4Ckwwf0sIBCFEACU0AEcQNCEAOQwAW3YjRAByAHE2mkZyjDAAaz4ACWratAaQBZdesH6C2ARjZHQsXHwEElj6ZLY4YEGRscmZtGkQ1G4ygU1myicQA)

The problem with this solution is that it does not allow you to specify only one of the type parameters, you mist specify both (the `<Payload, typeof RequestName>` part in the call). This is because Typescript does not allow for partial inference, either all types parameters are specified, or all are inferred.

There can be two solutions to this. The first one is to use function currying, so we can have the first type parameter inferred and the second specified. This works but leads to a somewhat ugly call site:

```
function createAction<Type extends string>(type: Type) {
  return <Payload,>() => (payload: Payload) => ({ type, payload });
};
interface Payload {
  howAreYou: boolean;
}
const RequestName = 'GoodThanksHowAreYou';
const action = createAction(RequestName)<Payload>();
```

The other solution is to use a dummy value to represent the type. This is just to let TS  infer the type from the parameters. This can be as simple as just asserting `null` is whatever type we want, or we could hide the ugliness behind  some other construct:

```
function createAction<Payload, Type extends string>(type: Type, payloadType: Payload) {
  return (payload: Payload) => ({ type, payload });
};
interface Payload {
  howAreYou: boolean;
}
const RequestName = 'GoodThanksHowAreYou';
const action = createAction(RequestName, null! as Payload);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQWvMAHgAUMBPAGzgwBMAaRAFTIAc1E0APbMGgZ0R8oKGGADmAPgAUUVmgBcTOQxbkqtZm0WlK1GgEpEAbwBQiROiggUSKat21tavYYC8ExFKOJZbFc9pEAF99AG4TIPDRbBRgDAh2HXUaYzNEAAs4AHccdABNOBBFACM4OApMMHCgkwgEIUQAJTQARxA0IQA5DABbdldEAHIAcTKaRnSMMABrPgAJbNy0ApBB8LqwBvjYBEQB1ExsPB2wKWa2jqhuvoYwEAoKAEJEDAEkl1CgA)

Or:

```
class Type<T> { __dummy!: T }
function type<T>(){ return new Type<T>() }
function createAction<Payload, T extends string>(type: T, payloadType: Type<Payload>) {
  return (payload: Payload) => ({ type, payload });
};
interface Payload {
  howAreYou: boolean;
}
const RequestName = 'GoodThanksHowAreYou';
const action = createAction(RequestName, type<Payload>());
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgHlgPmgb2gfTwBMBXAW1PgEIAuOaAXwCgAzYgO2ABcBLAezeickaTAAoAlLgBOyTsSkC2yAO5xh6DBIYt2XPgOAywnZAEE9-VAAUw8ELzCEANHWQAPE20IwInKdzYAc00hFFpYF0Rbe0cEMLUUa2iHQgxxHEZoaBk5BWhRKLsU2hsix3SAXixRXFDkSOTHBnEAbkZ6NoCTKWYwYGRoUpjCDKyAC15lUxkATV5iWgAjXl4QZDA2NqZgfl9oACVkAEdiZF8AOTBSAYroAHIAcRXCWDGNgGsIAAlJ6eQ54h3No7Nh7Po8fjQW6GdYmcwQtiiQ4nM6cS7XFx1JJlVISVpAA)